# Updating Membership Terms of Service

Tags: members, registration, themes, register

EE 5.2.5

I'm trying to update the ToS message for member signups.

When a user goes to `domain.com/member/register` and sees this form:

[image]

In the [docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/settings/members.html#require-terms-of-service) it says you can change this at `Design --> Themes --> Member Profile Templates --> Default --> Registration Form` but I actually don't know what that means.

Is that a path in the admin panel? If so, I don't see any `Design` page or link anywhere. Is it in the file structure? If so, again, I don't see any `Design` directory.

Are the docs out of date or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the Control Panel. If you don't see a design section, it means the user group your member is in doesn't have permission to see the Design section.

[image]

**EDIT**

Ahh, for some reason I thought you were using EE2. The area of the documentation you mention is out dated. I will provide the correct link to follow to create a copy of the built in templates so you can edit them freely:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/member/index.html#member-profile-templates

Follow these instruction to copy the templates to your themes folder and then edit them how you see fit.

Comment: Wow, that CP looks completely different than anything I've seen. Is that supposed to be the admin CP, like `domain.com/admin.php`? The navigation, styling, breadcrumb, everything looks totally unfamiliar.

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry, for some reason thought you were talking about EE2.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to edit it.